# Sign in with phone using firebase getting error 400 and captcha

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to sign in on my react app using firebase with phone.
I am using a useContext to creat the login function and I use it in my signIn.js component.

```
const signIn = (phone) => {
        const recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {},
        auth);
        recaptchaVerifier.render();
        signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, phone, recaptchaVerifier);
    }



    // display form
    const [modalState, setModalState] = useState({
        signInModal: false
    });


    return(
        <UserContext.Provider value={{modalState, toggleModals, signIn, auth}}>
            {props.children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
```

This is a useContext component

and in my sign in page:

```
const handleForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(input.current[0].value.length < 10){
      setValidation("Number not correct");
      return;
    }
    try{
      const res = await signIn(phoneNumber);
      console.log(res);
      /*
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        window.confirmationResult = res;
      })*/
      //setPhoneNumber("");
      setValidation("");
      //console.log(cred);

    }catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      setValidation(err);
    }
  }
```

I get an error 400 I don't know why...

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of that error logged?  It might have some more details than just 400

Comment: screenshot added

Comment: Can you try adding `console.log(phoneNumber)` and check if the phone number is valid as the error says?

Comment: I get the number I put in the input but without the +.